# Valid UK telephone regex with extensions

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I need a regex for php that allows 0-9, the string ext, spaces and + (for UK telephone numbers, ext is for extension). here is my attempt which doesn't work:

```
/^[\d -(ext)]+$/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like this: "\+?[\d ]+(ext)?[\d ]+"

Comment: This regex doesn't even begin to try and *validate* a phone number (it would also accept `-----` and other nonsensical combinations. Is that OK with you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the string out of the character class:

```
/^([\d -]+|ext)+$/
```

To allow `ext` just once:

```
/^[\d -]+(ext)?[\d -]+$/
```

Comment: +1, although that would permit multiple "ext" instances, and presumably it should only be allowed once.

Answer (score 0):

**Straight from Google...**

Examples of accepted numbers:

02081234567

0208 123 4567

020 8123 4567

0208 123-4567

+44 208 123 4567

+44 (0) 208 123 4567

01234 567 890

+44 0 1234 567-890

07712 123 456

Examples of numbers that will not be accepted:

020812345678
123456789
07612 123 4567
+33 345 876 1298

```
/^(((44))( )?|((+44))( )?|(+44)( )?|(44)( )?)?((0)|((0)))?( )?(((1[0-9]{3})|(7[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2})|(20)( )?[7-8]{1})( )?([0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{3})|(2[0-9]{2}( )?[0-9]{3}[ -]?[0-9]{4}))$/
```